# Why isn't this navigation menu working properly?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is a bootstrap navigation menu which is placed above the main menu (fixed), I'm not sure what the problem exactly is! I want it to be in one row.

[This is the fixed-top navbar:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdAkh.png)

[and this is how the navbar that I want it to be above it looks, it covers the fixed-top navbar and it doesn't show properly:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiXPF.png)

Below is the navigation menu code:

```
<nav class="navbar justify-content-between">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <p class="navbar-text">Already have an account?</p>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b><span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">Login
            <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                  <div class="help-block text-right">
                    <a href="">Forget the password ?</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                  </label>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom text-center">New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I appreciate your help.

[image: As you can see the menu overlaps with the menu below it and also I cannot press the login link]

Comment: Please give some more details what you want to do.

Comment: I edited the question and added pictures so you know what the problem is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CSS

```
        img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu{
    background-color:  #49f357;
    }

    .dropdown-menu{
        right: 0 !important;
    }

    .dropdown-toggle{ 
      background-color:#2de03c;
    }

    .dropdown-toggle > .active { color: aqua;}

    .dropdown-toggle:hover {background-color: #0eb41c;}

    .dropdown-menu > .active > a,.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {color: white!important; background-color: #e7e7e7!important;}
    
    .dropdown-item{
        background-color: #2de03c;
    }

    .dropdown-menu-center {
      left: 50% !important;
      right: auto !important;
      text-align: center !important;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
    }

    .textwhite{
        color:white ;
    }    

      .collapse ul.navbar-nav> .nav-item > a {
      color: white;
    }
      
      /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
      .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      
      
      .nav-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
        height: auto !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
      }
      
      .navbar{
        position: sticky

      }
```

HTML

```
     <div class="d-none d-xl-block p-0">
    <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: #10c720;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04"
        aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mb-2" id="navbarsExample04">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active" style="margin-left: 150px;">
            <a routerLink="/Home" class="nav-link ml-2 mt-2 mr-2 fontsize" href="#">HOME <span
                class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-2 mt-2 mr-2">
            <a routerLink="/About" class="nav-link fontsize">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li *ngIf='isMale' class="nav-item ml-2 mt-2">
            <a routerLink="/Bride" class="nav-link fontsize">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li *ngIf='isFemale' class="nav-item ml-2 mt-2">
          <li class="nav-item ml-2 mt-2 mr-2">
            <a routerLink="/Contact" class="nav-link fontsize">CONTACT</a>
          </li>

        </ul>



        <div class="dropdown text-center border border-danger ">
          <button class="btn btn-success   dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Login
          </button>
          <div class="row border border-primary">
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center border border-danger" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

              <div class="">Login
                <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address"
                      required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password"
                      required>
                    <div class="help-block text-right">
                      <a href="">Forget the password ?</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="bottom text-center">New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your help, but the menu you gave me overlapped with the menu below it and I cannot press the login link.

Comment: I used bootstrap so try to import bootstrap 4.0 CDN link.

Comment: try to give margin top to the dropdown menu of login.